# Oracle PL SQL works from SQL Dev. but not from the code

Tags: c#, oracle, plsql, plsqldeveloper

I'm slowly going nuts here...why does this peace of SQL code work from SQL Developer 
and not from C#?

```
declare x integer;
begin
insert into aspa2_counters (shortname, description, devicegroupid) values ('TEST0', 'DESC0', 61) returning counterid into x;
INSERT ALL  
INTO aspa2_priceclass (from_num, to_num, price, fk_counterid) VALUES (0,100,0.22,x) 
INTO aspa2_priceclass (from_num, to_num, price, fk_counterid) VALUES (101,200,0.23,x) 
SELECT * FROM dual; 
end;
```

Multiple inserts are dynamically generated in the code.
Please help...I've spent two days on this one and it's slowing down the project.
Please, do require more info if needed.

Thank you!

EDIT: I forgot to write down an error:

> ```
> ORA-06550: line 1, column 19:
> PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "" when expecting one of the following:
>
>    begin function package pragma procedure subtype type use
>    <an identifier> <a double-quoted delimited-identifier> form
>    current cursor
> ```

Comment: if u say it won't work from C#, post the C# code

Comment: For debugging purposes, I have hardcoded upper PLSQL statement...so I guess the code is not relevant.

Comment: can you show us the hardcoded statement as it is in the c# code ? I mean something like: string sqlStr = "declare x integer; begin ...";

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, I finally solved the problem.

Looks like Oracle's odp.net is very sensitive to newline chars ("\r\n" & "\n"), so make sure 
you dont use @ for multiline strings, or try using .replace() method to replace "\r\n" with "\n".

This is how it looks in the end:

```
string anonymousBlock = "declare x integer;" +
                        "begin " +
                        "insert into aspa2_counters (shortname, description, devicegroupid) values (:p1, :p2, :p3) returning counterid into x;" +
                          buildInsert.ToString() + 
                        " end;";
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's hardcoded part:

```
string query = @"declare x integer;
                      begin
                      insert into aspa2_counters (shortname, description, devicegroupid) values ('TEST', 'OPIS', 61) returning counterid into x;
                      INSERT ALL  
                          INTO aspa2_priceclass (from_num, to_num, price, fk_counterid) VALUES (0,100,0.22,x) 
                          INTO aspa2_priceclass (from_num, to_num, price, fk_counterid) VALUES (101,200,0.23,x) 
                      SELECT * FROM dual; 
                      end;";
```

and code Oracle command code:

```
            using (OracleCommand cmnd = new OracleCommand(cmndText, con))
            {
                if (parameters != null)
                {
                    foreach (OracleParameter p in parameters)
                    {
                        cmnd.Parameters.Add(p);
                    }
                }

                try
                {
                    cmnd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {

                }
            }
```